# DNS A Record not pointing to website IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Wordpress on 35.154.205.172

I pointed my domain (timespade.com) to the particular IP address, but the same is resulting in an error. The IP address is working fine.

I have attached the screenshots of my A Name and C Name records

Website not loading

[image]

A Record

[image]

C Record

[image]

Comment: IP works for me, this suggests an issue with your DNS configuration, check that the nameservers are set correctly. Sorry can't help more as I'm not familiar with aws.

Comment: Can you also post the domain control panel configuration?

Comment: Checking the status with `nslookup` is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I see that you are creating the records in your `AWS DNS control panel`, but the domain name's name servers are pointed to `GoDaddy's name servers`. You need to go to `GoDaddy` and change the name servers to the four servers the NS records are pointed to (screenshot `A Record` or `C Record`).
Note that the propagation of the name servers might take some time.

Comment: Hi. The problem was resolved. The problem was with the app, not with the DNS :O

Actually, in ServerPilot, there was a setting which blocked unknown IPs from accessing app. Turned out to be the reason for the website not showing up.